# How to ignore None value from list?

Tags: robotframework, jsonpath

I am testing BE and when getting json path for some values I get **None**. I want to ignore them.
**Remove values from list** did not work for me.

```
Remove values from list  ${list}    None/${empty}/null
```

Are there any other ways to ignore **None** value?

[image]

I also tried to get from json values without null but did not work either. Showed an error

*JsonPathLexerError: Error on line 1, col 41: Unexpected character: ?*

```
${TARGET_TEXT}=    Get Json Path    ${RESPONSE}    $.pipelines..filter.children..targetText[?!@.None]
```

Comment: Try `[?(!@.None)]` (with parentheses). I don't know what system you're using, so I can't be of much more help than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. You need to remove `${NONE}` rather than `${EMPTY}`

```
Remove values from list  ${TARGET_TEXT}  ${NONE}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
${list} =   Evaluate    [i for i in ${list} if i]
```

Comment: While this would probably work in this specific case, your solution will remove other non-None values, such as the integer zero or an empty string.